# Is there a way to get Media callbacks following a MediaResponse?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

After sending a `MediaResponse` and starting to stream audio, if the user says "pause", the Assistant pauses the playback, is there a way to get a callback to that event for tracking playback position purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not currently supported. The only events you can handle with a callback is FINISHED or STATUS_UNSPECIFIED.